# High chart zone color based on value is end up in displaying both the colors if the value is equal or if the value is .001 less or more

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Expected behaviour
Is it possible to display red color if the value is <= 10

Actual behaviour
Even it display both the color until from 9.95 to 9.95 suppose to be red

Live demo with steps to reproduce
https://jsfiddle.net/sivakma/g2yLe1sw/4/

Product version
Highcharts JS v11.2.0 (2023-10-30)

Affected browser(s)
All browsers

```
HTML:
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

Script:

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [0, 5,7, 10,9.95,9.95,11.25, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0,],
        zones: [{
            value: 10,
            color: 'red'
        }, {
            color: 'green'
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: This is about the "lineWidth" property. The zones are functioning correctly, but the line is broader, causing it to display a different color. You can see this more clearly in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ocpesr52/. When the default "lineWidth" is set to 2, you'll need to change the value to 10.1 for proper adjustment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sdkwc8t4/

Comment: Thank you for your response, even in my sample if i adjust the value to 10.1 its working but as per my requirement the value below 10 should be displayed in red color . i have a restrictions to not change the value which will miss lead to other issues.

Comment: You can wrap the getZone function, and achieve the red point when <=10 https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mukp75ht/ When it comes to the paths, it might be difficult, because it meets the zoneAxis  y conception, however i understand your use case and perhaps this is something that should be improved. Feel free to add your feature request using the following GitHub link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Comment: Actually I have reported an issue already but unfortunately they closed the issue saying this is the behavior intended . [ https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20074]

Comment: I see, in that case the only workaround for this issue is to set a bit higher zone value https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fbnzhw1g/